# Sitecore - upload xlsx data & create a client panel for editing line item data

Tags: database, api, sitecore, panel, xlsx

I am fairly new to Sitecore...

I have mulitple clients who will be giving me a XLSX spreadsheet, with about 5 columns containing data/information.

1. I firstly want to upload this XLSX - this is a 1off, just for the
   initial upload.
2. After it's uploaded the xlsx won't be needed anymore, but I want
   each client to have their own frontend panel, where they can see
   each row from the XLSX.
3. They also need the ability to edit existing rows of data and also be
   able to create new line items.

I need tyo document the idea - so what would be the best approach in Sitecore to do this?

Comment: It is not possible in Sitecore out of the box. Look for some 3rd party solutions

Comment: ...and once I have the data from the xlsx in place, what would be the best approach for a frontend client login to see/edit that data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the editing pane you would want to create a new "Application" using [SPEAK](https://doc.sitecore.net/speak), and configure this application to be accessible from either the Dashboard or the Desktop/Shell.

Each SPEAK application is effectively a standalone .Net page that can be built and styled however you like.

Your method for uploading the intial data would probably depend on how you plan to store it, which in turn would depend on how many, and what type of records you need to be storing and editing. There's no once size fits all solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a controller action to accept the file upload and save it to the Media Library. Then the item for editing the data would have a controller rendering could read the xlsx from the Media Library with [Office Open XML libraries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc850837.aspx), convert the data to JSON and output it on the page. The page would use an editor like [TableSorter JS](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) to display it and allow for editing. You'd call another controller action from TableSorter to save the data back to Excel and update the item in the Media Library. Potentially you could create new versions of the items in the Media Library when they're editing to allow for rollbacks.